# Get variables from javascript and build a sql query on php for jQuery-Seat-Charts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm using [jQuery-Seat-Charts](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts/tree/gh-pages) to build a simple booking system (if i can name it a system) for our company buses. Since I'm not expert on javascript, i need your precious help on figuring out how to get this done. What i just want is to get the variables from the javascript and build a sql query on php to store the whole informations in the MySQL database. What i have now is the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="seat-map">
                <div class="front-indicator">Front</div>

            </div>
            <div id="legend"></div>
            <div class="booking-details">
                <h2>Booking Details</h2>

                <h3> Selected Seats (<span id="counter">0</span>):</h3>
                <ul id="selected-seats"></ul>

                Total: <b><span id="total">0</span> &#8364;</b>

                <button class="checkout-button">Book&raquo;</button>

            </div>
            <div id="formulari">
                <ul id="formulari-ul"> </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="`jquery.seat-charts.js`"></script>

    <script>
        var firstSeatLabel = 1;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
                $formulari = $('#formulari-ul'),
                $counter = $('#counter'),
                $total = $('#total'),
                sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
                map: [
                    '___f',
                    'ff',
                    'ee_e',
                    'ee_e',
                    'ee_e',
                    'eeee',
                ],
                seats: {
                    f: {
                        price   : 60,
                        classes : 'first-class', //your custom CSS class
                        category: 'First Class'
                    },
                    e: {
                        price   : 55,
                        classes : 'other-seats', //your custom CSS class
                        category: 'Other Seats'
                    }                   

                },
                naming : {
                    top : false,
                    getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
                        return firstSeatLabel++;
                    },
                },
                legend : {
                    node : $('#legend'),
                    items : [
                        [ 'f', 'available',   'First Class' ],
                        [ 'e', 'available',   'Other Seats'],
                        [ 'f', 'unavailable', 'Booked']
                    ]                   
                },
                click: function () {
                    if (this.status() == 'available') {
                        //let's create a new <li> which we'll add to the cart items
                        $('<li><strong>Seat #'+this.settings.label+' - Price: '+this.data().price+'&#8364; </strong> ('+this.data().category+') <a href="#" class="cancel-cart-item">[cancel]</a></li>')
                            .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                            .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                            .appendTo($cart);

                        $('<p><strong>[X] Seat #'+this.settings.label+':</strong> <input name="fullname" type="text" value="Full Name" /><input name="birthday" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" size="10" /><input name="placeBirth type="text" value="Place" size="10" /><input name="nrPass" type="text" value="Nr Pass" size="10" /><input name="passFrom" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" size="10" /><input name="passTo" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" size="10" /></p>')
                            .attr('id', 'form-item-'+this.settings.id)
                            .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                            .appendTo($formulari);

                        /*
                         * Lets update the counter and total
                         *
                         * .find function will not find the current seat, because it will change its stauts only after return
                         * 'selected'. This is why we have to add 1 to the length and the current seat price to the total.
                         */
                        $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+this.data().price);

                        return 'selected';
                    } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
                        //update the counter
                        $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                        //and total
                        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-this.data().price);

                        //remove the item from our cart
                        $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();

                        //seat has been vacated
                        return 'available';
                    } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
                        //seat has been already booked
                        return 'unavailable';
                    } else {
                        return this.style();
                    }
                }
            });

            //this will handle "[cancel]" link clicks
            $('#selected-seats').on('click', '.cancel-cart-item', function () {
                //let's just trigger Click event on the appropriate seat, so we don't have to repeat the logic here
                sc.get($(this).parents('li:first').data('seatId')).click();
            });

            //let's pretend some seats have already been booked
            sc.get(['1_4']).status('unavailable');

    });

    function recalculateTotal(sc) {
        var total = 0;

        //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
        sc.find('selected').each(function () {
            total += this.data().price;
        });

        return total;
    }

    </script>
```

As you can see, i have the function on click that, when the user clicks on any available seat, will appear a form that should be filled from the user with it's details. I have progressed until here, and now i don't know how to get the javascript variables as seat number, seat price, and seat code (all seats are coded like X_Y where X = the row and Y = the seat number at that row); and build a sql query with those variables and with informations from the form.
 Hope that I was clear on explaining my needs and issue, and that someone can help me on putting me on the right track ;-)
Thanks to everyone!

P.S. The jquery.seat-chart.js file can be found [here](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts/blob/gh-pages/jquery.seat-charts.js)!

Answer (score 0):

Hello to everyone 
By searching for many days, and testing many ways, i came across to this solution. Probably will be helpful for anyone else that have or will have the same problem I had.
As you can see, I have removed at all the id `#formulari` and the div for it, since I decided to make the whole process multi-steps. So, what i did firstly (STEP 1) is adding some hidden input for every seat selected; created a form practically with POST to pass the seatNR and seatCode to the next step; and getting some information about the client such as Name, Phone Number and Email:

```
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="col_12">
                <legend><strong>Details for person of contact</strong></legend>
            <div class="col_4">
                <label for="rezname"><strong>Your Name</strong> </label>
                <input id="rezEmri" name="rezEmri" type="text" class="col_12" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="col_4">
                <label for="rezEmail"><strong>Your Email</strong> <span>where the reservation details will be sent</span></label>
                <input id="rezEmail" name="rezEmail" type="text" class="col_12" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="col_4">
                <label for="rezTel"><strong>Your Phone Nr</strong> </label>
                <input id="rezTel" name="rezTel" type="text" class="col_12" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="seat-map">
            <div class="front-indicator">Front</div>

        </div>
        <div id="legend"></div>
        <div class="booking-details">
            <form action="transport.php?step=2" method="post">
            <h2>Booking Details</h2>

            <h3> Selected Seats (<span id="counter">0</span>):</h3>
            <ul id="selected-seats"></ul>

            Total: <b><span id="total">0</span> &#8364;</b>

            <button class="checkout-button">Next &raquo;</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="`jquery.seat-charts.js`"></script>

<script>
    var firstSeatLabel = 1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
            $counter = $('#counter'),
            $total = $('#total'),
            sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
            map: [
                '___f',
                'ff',
                'ee_e',
                'ee_e',
                'ee_e',
                'eeee',
            ],
            seats: {
                f: {
                    price   : 60,
                    classes : 'first-class', //your custom CSS class
                    category: 'First Class'
                },
                e: {
                    price   : 55,
                    classes : 'other-seats', //your custom CSS class
                    category: 'Other Seats'
                }                   

            },
            naming : {
                top : false,
                getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
                    return firstSeatLabel++;
                },
            },
            legend : {
                node : $('#legend'),
                items : [
                    [ 'f', 'available',   'First Class' ],
                    [ 'e', 'available',   'Other Seats'],
                    [ 'f', 'unavailable', 'Booked']
                ]                   
            },
            click: function () {
                    if (this.status() == 'available') {
                        <?php /*?>//let's create a new <li> which we'll add to the cart items<?php */?>
                        $('<li><strong>Seat #'+this.settings.label+' - Price: '+this.data().price+'&#8364; </strong> ('+this.data().category+') <a href="#" class="cancel-cart-item" style="color: #b71a4c;">[cancel]</a><input type="hidden" name="seatNR['+this.settings.label+']" value="'+this.settings.label+'"><input type="hidden" name="seatCode['+this.settings.label+']" value="'+this.settings.id+'"></li>')
                            .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                            .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                            .appendTo($cart);


                        .attr('id', 'form-item-'+this.settings.id)
                        .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                        .appendTo($formulari);

                    /*
                     * Lets update the counter and total
                     *
                     * .find function will not find the current seat, because it will change its stauts only after return
                     * 'selected'. This is why we have to add 1 to the length and the current seat price to the total.
                     */
                    $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                    $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+this.data().price);

                    return 'selected';
                } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
                    //update the counter
                    $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                    //and total
                    $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-this.data().price);

                    //remove the item from our cart
                    $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();

                    //seat has been vacated
                    return 'available';
                } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
                    //seat has been already booked
                    return 'unavailable';
                } else {
                    return this.style();
                }
            }
        });

        //this will handle "[cancel]" link clicks
        $('#selected-seats').on('click', '.cancel-cart-item', function () {
            //let's just trigger Click event on the appropriate seat, so we don't have to repeat the logic here
            sc.get($(this).parents('li:first').data('seatId')).click();
        });

        //let's pretend some seats have already been booked
        sc.get(['1_4']).status('unavailable');

});

function recalculateTotal(sc) {
    var total = 0;

    //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
    sc.find('selected').each(function () {
        total += this.data().price;
    });

    return total;
}

</script>
```

STEP 2 = > I get the variables from the POST on the STEP 1, and process the informations like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['step']) && (mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['step']))=='2')) {
            $seatNR = $_POST['seatNR'];
            $seatCode = $_POST['seatCode'];
           // I'm not showing the client details process, as it's clear the way i do it :)
```

P.S. The details of the person of contact are registered in the db and will be associated with the traveler details of that specific reservation/booking. This way, we have the details of the person who made the booking, associated with the details of all travelers.

After i filter inputs and make the needed verification (specific on my system where this seat selector will be integrated), I show the input fields where the visitor will put the traveler details (Name, Passport Nr, etc). And this is the way i did it:

```
<?php
foreach( $seatNR as $key => $n ) {
  print '<tr>'; 
  print ' <td><strong style="font-size:14px;"><center>'.$n.'</center></strong></td>
  ';
  print '<td><input type="text" name="trav[][Name]" size="20" value=""></td>
  ';
  print '<td><input type="text" name="trav[][Birthday]" size="9" value=""></td>
  ';
  print '<td><input type="text" name="trav[][PlaceBirth]" size="14" value=""></td>
  ';
  print '<td><input type="text" name="trav[][passNr]" size="10" value=""></td>
  ';
  print '<input type="hidden" name="trav[][seatNR]" value="'.$n.'">
  ';
  print '<input type="hidden" name="trav[][seatCode]" value="'.$kodiVendit[$key].'">
  ';

  print '</tr>';
}
?>
```

So, with this `foreach` will appear as many rows as the visitor selected seats. If visitor selected 5 seats, will appear 5 rows of input fields.

STEP 3 => Will get the whole informations from the form at STEP 2, and, after the verification that all informations are as they supposed to be, will be inserted in the MySQL database.

So, this is what i have done. If anyone of you have any suggestion to do it better, i'll be very happy to know it.

Best luck to everyone ;-)

**EDIT:** I forgot to add the loop for the form procesor. Is as follows:

```
// To get the last id of reservation and to insert it at traveler details.
// This way we create a connection btw the traveleres and who made the reservation
$sql33="SELECT rezID, rezDataRez FROM transport_reservations ORDER BY rezID DESC LIMIT 1;";
            $res33=mysql_query($sql33)or die(mysql_error().$sql33);
            $row33=mysql_fetch_array($res33);
            $$lastRezID=$row33[0];
// Start the verification and insertion of traveler details on the db
 define('HOST', '*********');
    define('DBNAME', '*********');
    define('USERNAME', '**********');
    define('PASSWORD', '********');
    $dbREZ = new mysqli(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DBNAME);

    $dataREZ = array();            
    foreach ($_POST['trav'] as $a) {
    /**
    * sanitize string data and format dates
    */  
    $dataREZ[] = sprintf("('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                $dbREZ->real_escape_string($lastRezID),
                $dbREZ->real_escape_string($a['Name']),
                date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a['Birthday'])),
                $dbREZ->real_escape_string($a['PlaceBirth']),
                $dbREZ->real_escape_string($a['passNr']),
                $dbREZ->real_escape_string($a['seatNr']),
                $dbREZ->real_escape_string($a['seatCode']),
                );

}
$sqlAddTrav = "INSERT INTO transport_travelers (rezID, travName, travBirthday, travBirthPlace, travPass, travSeatNr, travSeatCode) VALUES \n" . join(",\n", $dataREZ);
$dbREZ->query($sqlAddTrav);
```

Hope it was clear.

Comment: where can I see your system on the web?

Comment: Hi @kleidi i'd like to receive other information about what you have done